# Only one triangle drawn

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, rendering

I am trying to render a quad with gl render mode GL_TRIANGLES with using element array buffer. Here is some code to explain process. Only the first 3 elements of indices array are drawn as expected. But following indices doesn't drawn at all.

Mesh Creation

```
glm::vec3 vertices[] = { glm::vec3(-1, 1, 0),
                          glm::vec3(-1, -1, 0),
                          glm::vec3(1, -1, 0),
                          glm::vec3(1, 1, 0)
                        };

glm::vec2 textures[] = { glm::vec2(1, 0),
                          glm::vec2(0, 0),
                          glm::vec2(0, 1),
                          glm::vec2(1, 1)
                        };

unsigned int indices[] = { 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2};
Mesh* mesh = new Mesh(vertices, sizeof(vertices) / sizeof(glm::vec3), textures, sizeof(textures) / sizeof(glm::vec2), indices, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(unsigned int), texture);
```

Mesh Class

```
Mesh::Mesh(...){
    InitMesh(...);
}

void Mesh::InitMesh(vec3* vertices, unsigned int numVertices, vec2* textureCoords, unsigned int numTextureCoords, unsigned int* indices, unsigned int numIndices) {
     this->numIndices = numIndices;

    // Generate VAO and bind
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID);
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    // Generate VBOs
    glGenBuffers(3, vboIDs);
    // Bind Position Buffer, Buffer Position Data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIDs[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numVertices * sizeof(vec3), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    // Buffer TextureCoord Data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIDs[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numTextureCoords * sizeof(vec2), textureCoords, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    // Buffer Indices Data
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboIDs[2]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, numIndices * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // Unbind VAO
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

void Mesh::Draw() {
    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Comment: Is the index buffer bound when you call drawElements?

Comment: @Bálint Yes, On InitMesh function(it is called by constructor). Fourth line from bottom of InitMesh.

Comment: @BarışDoğaYavaş Please post an answer instead of putting the solution in your question, so others can see it has an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

After several hours of searching found the issue on creation of vboIDs[]. I was creating it by size 2, changed it to 3 and fixed the issue.

Comment: If your variable vboIDs was a std::vector<GLuint>, then you could do

// Generate VBOs
vboIDs.resize(3);
glGenBuffers(vboIDs.size(), &vboIDs[0]);

to avoid having to update 2 places with the constant 3.